# How to show preceding zero in csv export?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have this block of code that saves info to csv.  The problem I'm facing is the preceding 0's are not being shown in excel although they show in notepad.
Is this a programming problem or excel csv conversion problem.  Any suggestions are appreciated.
code:

```
  public bool SaveToCSV(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();

            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                              Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                              ToArray();

            var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
            lines.Add(header);

            var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
            lines.AddRange(valueLines);

            File.WriteAllLines(FileName, lines);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: If you want Excel to treat your value as a string, enclose it in `"`

Comment: This might be formatting issue in Excel..u may try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/81518/using-a-custom-number-format-to-display-leading-zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the preceding 0's are not being shown in excel although they show in notepad

You can:

- *Import* (instead of *Open*) the data in your `csv` and make sure to set the column(s) that you want treated as `text` to be imported as `text`, and not interpreted by Excel as numeric, **or**;
- change the way you output your `csv` to include an apostrophe `'` prefix to numeric data you want to be treated as `text` by Excel when it *opens* the file - e.g. `'0123456`

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but if you are interested in adding an All-0's row, consider the following code that simply adds a row of 0s to your CSV:

```
public bool SaveToCSV(DataTable dt, string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                          ToArray();

        var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
        lines.Add(header);

        //New Code Starts Here
        List<string> zeroList = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++){
            zeroList.Add("0");
        }

        lines.AddRange(zeroList);
        //New Code Ends Here

        var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
        lines.AddRange(valueLines);

        File.WriteAllLines(FileName, lines);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        return false;
    }   
}
```